# Counting values and inserting result into dataframe using vectorization in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a datasheet with 35k+ lines in the following format:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| username |  event  | points_value |
+----------+---------+--------------+
| user1    | event_1 | 100          |
| user2    | event_2 | 120          |
| user2    | event_1 | 100          |
| ...      | ...     | ...          |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Not sure if relevant but there are 20 possible events and an event can happen more than once per user. The data is sorted based on time of the event, not by username or event type. I'm looking to count the number of events per user (and points added per user and event but that's a problem that will be solved by solving the one I pose below).

My output dataframe, events_total_df, uses the following format:

```
+----------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
| username | event_1 | event_2 | ... | event_20 |
+----------+---------+---------+-----+----------+
```

(I've pre-filled the events_total_df dataframe with the usernames and filled every event column with a 0)

I already have a solution for the issue:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    event_totals_df.loc[event_totals_df.username.eq(row['username']), row['event']] += 1
```

This is, however, a very slow solution. With the current datasheet of 35k+ lines (which is for one week of events) it takes minutes to complete. I've done some research and it seems like vectorization is the way to go, as it's a lot quicker. However, I can't get it to work. What I'd, ideally, like to do is something like this:

```
event_group = df.groupby('event')
for event in list(event_group.groups.keys()):
    event_totals_df[event] = len(df.loc[ event_group.get_group(event)['username'] == event_totals_df['username'] ])
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Which makes sense. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do with vectorization? I'm open to changing basically anything to quicken it up. But I don't think it's an issue with how I've tackled the output dataframe?

Comment: ``df.pivot('username', 'event', 'points_value')`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['points_value'], index=['user'], columns=['event'], aggfunc={'points_value':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

This will sum all the points for each event per user.